# How to add User Custom Control (.dll develeoped in Net 2.0) in ASP.NET CORE project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

How to add User Custom Control (.dll developed in Net 2.0) in ASP.NET CORE project?

I have added .dlls in assembly under dependencies. I can able to access the properties and methods of dll. but I don't know how to render in HTML view?

Comment: A quick google search would have given you a lot of results. https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/321749/how-to-register-an-assembly-in-a-webform-to-use-a-custom-control

Comment: Already surfed lot. all solutions related to ASP.NET Web Forms. But I need ASP.NET CORE with MVC Razor

Comment: I can nou understand your question.

Comment: I would suspect that a WebForms Custom Control is fundamentally incompatible with any MVC view engine.  Writing the same functionality into a tag helper or partial view seems a lot more idiomatic to the platform.

Comment: I think this is what you want. `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly` and `BuildManager.GetObjectFactory` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021054/buildmanager-addreferencedassembly-and-buildmanager-getobjectfactory

Comment: Pierre  - No. I want load my user control in razor view.

Comment: David - Your thoughts I agree. so no upgrade for custom user control after ASP.NET forms to ASP.NET MVC. rite?

Comment: @PrabhuManoharan: I've certainly never heard of anybody successfully making that work.  And my understanding of the two platforms would preclude any helpful ideas on my part.  I really think it's just not possible.  (Or at least not without significant effort in forking the source code for the target framework to add your own support for it.  Which would be orders of magnitude more difficult than just writing the functionality in the newer framework.)